# How to restrict associated tables from getting considered for join when using hibernate update() on entity having multiple @ManyToOne associations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a Record entity that maintains a `@ManyToOne` relation with Product_Category table and Price_Category table. The record entity also maintains a `@OneToMany` association with another table called PendingRecords.

Currently this is working perfectly for hibernate save/persist, in which all the associated tables also get modified when specific conditions are met. The problem is these associated entities are also getting considered on hibernate update/delete which is not what I intended to do. I want to restrict these entites from getting considered and allow change only on insert.

Following are the entity class mappings

`Record.java`

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_RECORDS")
public class Record {

-------------------------


@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "PRICE_CATEGORY", referencedColumnName="price_category", nullable=false)
private PriceCategory price_category;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_CATEGORY", referencedColumnName="product_category", nullable=false)
private ProductCategory product_category;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="record", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private PendingRecords pendingRecord;

----------------------

(getter setter methods)

-----------------------
```

Following are the associated tables

`PriceCategory.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRICE_CATEGORY")
public class PriceCategory{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "PRICE_CATEGORY")
private String price_category;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

----------------------------

 (getter-setters)

----------------------------
```

`ProductCategory.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_CATEGORY")
public class ProductCategory {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "PRODUCT_CATEGORY")
private String product_category;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

----------------------------

 (getter-setters)

----------------------------
```

and finally,

`PendingRecords.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PENDING_RECORDS")
public class PendingRecords{


@Id
@Column(name = "PENDING_RECORD_NO")
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
@GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign",parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="record"))
private Long pending_record_id;

----------------------

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Record record;

-------------------------

(getters-setters)

-------------------------
```

The entity associations are working fine when I perform the insert (hibernate persist/save). The problem is when I try to update the Record, hibernate is trying to update all the associated entries also like

```
   select
   this_.RECORD_NO as REC_REC1_1_3_,

   this_.PRICE_CATEGORY as PRICE_CA10_1_3_,

   this_.PRODUCT_CATEGORY as PRODUCT11_1_3_,

   pricecatego2_.id as id1_0_0_,
   pricecatego2_.PRICE_CATEGORY as PRICE_CAT2_0_0_,
   pricecatego2_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_0_0_,
   productcat3_.ID as ID1_3_1_,
   productcat3_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT2_3_1_,
   productcat3_.PRODUCT_CATEGORY as PRODUCT_3_3_1_,
   pendingrec4_.PENDING_RECORD_NO as REC_REC1_2_2_,
   ---------------------------
  from
      ITEM_RECORDS this_ 
  inner join
      PRICE_CATEGORY pricecatego2_ 
          on this_.PRICE_CATEGORY=pricecatego2_.PRICE_CATEGORY 
  inner join
      PRODUCT_CATEGORY productcat3_ 
          on this_.PRODUCT_CATEGORY=productcat3_.PRODUCT_CATEGORY 
  left outer join
      PENDING_RECORDS pendingrec4_ 
          on this_.PENDING_RECORD_NO=pendingrec4_.PENDING_RECORD_NO 
  where
      this_.PENDING_RECORD_NO=?
```

What should be done to prevent considering these entities for join operations while updating Record entity? Because this is an additional overhead and also generates `ClassCastException`. I need associated entites to be changed only during persit or save and not during update or delete.

I am getting the following error during update

```
Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapps.models.PriceCategory cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
```

Should I specify CascadeType? Or should i use hibernate CascadeType instead of JPA's which I am currently using for PendingRecords? Or is there another way? Please help me resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does remove the CascadeType work for you?

Comment: @DavePateral Pardon me if I am wrong, but isnt `CascadeType.REMOVE` used when you need to remove entries from both the entities? Here it is already working. The problem is during updation bec all entities are getting updated which is not what I want. I want update to occur only for the entity for which I am calling the update(). Also as shown in the code above only one of the associate entities is using cascade option the other two entities are not. But when I call the update, hibernate is trying to update all the 4 entities.

Comment: The error indicates you don't implement the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: @DavePateral Thankyou I have noticed that but this problem occurs only bec those entities are getting considered for join operations during update. I dont want this to happen during update.

Comment: Well, how do you know the entities are being updated if an exception prevents the transaction from committing? Are you seeing `UPDATE` queries being sent to the db? Hibernate is (likely) not trying to update the *data belonging* to  `PriceCategory` and `ProductCategory`. It merely needs to check whether `Record.price_category` or `Record.product_category` has been set to a different entity instance (to see if the corresponding join column needs updating)

Comment: @crizzis. Thankyou... you are right. Hibernate is not trying to update, I have edited my question to point out the same. The problem is I dont want the join columns to get updated under any circumstances like you mentioned that hibernate check whether Record.price_category or Record.product_category has been set to a different entity instance (to see if the corresponding join column needs updating. Is there a way to avoid this check bec this is a unnecessary process. Will specifying a cascadetype help here? Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I am really a newbie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need associated entites to be changed only during persit or save
>   and not during update or delete

If, once the related entities are set at persist time, they should never be overwritten with another entity instance, use `@JoinColumn(updatable=false)`.

Note that because of Hibernate's flush operation order, it the related entities do not already exist, you might need to save them first, flush the `EntityManager`, and only then save the top-level entity.

> What should be done to prevent considering these entities for join
>   operations while updating Record entity?

Try `@ManyToOne(fetch=LAZY)`. I am not entirely sure this will work during a merge, though, as there are many reasons for Hibernate to fetch related entities during a merge. If it doesn't work, you might need to write a custom update query.